# Google Sketchup API - to a Windows App?

Tags: c#, ruby, api, 3d, sketchup

How can one interface with **[Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/)**, via the API, from a **Windows App?**

I was looking at something written in C#/VB.NET but its seems like the only available [**Google Sketchup API** is for Ruby](http://sketchupapi.blogspot.com/).

Any ideas on how to **use that Ruby API from .NET?** Is Ruby only serverside or can it be processed locally, offline?

Comment: Would IronRuby be useful here or would the Ruby in Sketchup be unable to talk to the Ruby in your .NET app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the Ruby API is just for script plugins, not for interfacing from a standalone app. Maybe you could add a Google Sketchup ruby plugin that interfaces with your app?

Answer (score 2):

There is a C++ API in addition to the Ruby Script system. Find it here:

http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/downloadsdksubmit.html

Comment: The C++ API is for reading and writing .skp files. Not for interfacing with the application.